# Automatically signing new kernel modules

Tags: kernel, secure-boot, dkms

In order to get around the whole "no unsigned modules" issue, I created a MOK so I can sign third-party modules. I have a script that I can use to sign modules en masse, but I'd like to streamline the process by automatically calling this script when new modules are installed. All the third party modules I have right now were built via DKMS, and I don't see that aspect changing any time soon.

So, the question is this: how would I go about automatically calling my signing script when DKMS finishes building a module?

Comment: If you Google there are several scripts at gift hub. See also https://computerlinguist.org/make-dkms-sign-kernel-modules-for-secure-boot-on-ubuntu-1604.html

Comment: @Panther I did a lot of Googling before posting this question, but I'll admit my Google-fu can be rather lacking at times. Fortunately for me, Ubuntu automatically signs modules as of 18.04; however, I imagine other folks will find the link you provided helpful, so thanks for that.

Comment: Since it appears your issue was solved in a more recent Ubuntu version, could you please mark this as closed by posting an answer and accepting it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newer versions of Ubuntu (18.04+) have solved this for me by signing modules automatically, but for anyone still in need of a solution, check out [this blog post](https://computerlinguist.org/make-dkms-sign-kernel-modules-for-secure-boot-on-ubuntu-1604.html) (thanks to [Panther](https://askubuntu.com/users/35795/panther) for finding it).